# Ruby - Remove HTML tags from CSV output

Tags: ruby, csv

The code below exports the conversations an inbox perfectly. However, because the inbox is web-based the `Message` field contains raw HTML tags;

```
<div>
Hello,<br><br>
I had my profile switched
</div>
```

I've tried to use `strip_tags` on the end of `threaded_conversation.threads.last.body` and `customer_message` but to no avail. Is there a correct way to leave this string only text?

```
CSV.open("conversations_#{mailbox_id}.csv", "wb", col_sep: ';', headers: true, force_quotes: false) do |csv|
  csv << ["Number", "From", "Subject", "Created", "Message"]
  conversations.each do |conversation|
    customer = conversation.customer
    threaded_conversation = helpscout.conversation(conversation.id)
    sleep(0.3)
    customer_message =
              begin
                body_message = threaded_conversation.threads.last.body
              rescue
                body_message = 'exception'
              end
    csv << [conversation.number, customer.email, conversation.subject, conversation.createdAt, customer_message]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a proper HTML library:

```
require 'nokogiri'
text = Nokogiri::HTML(body).text
# => "\nHello,\nI had my profile switched\n\n"
```